# Temporary namespace/context in Haskell

Tags: haskell, namespaces, dsl

In [Io](http://iolanguage.com), you can set the execution context using `do`:

```
Http := Object clone
Http get := method(uri, ("<GET request to " .. uri .. ">") println)
Http delete := method(uri, ("<DELETE request to " .. uri .. ">") println)

Database := Object clone
Database insert := method(table, data, ("<insert data to " .. table .. ">") println)
Database delete := method(table, id, ("<delete " .. id .. " from " .. table .. ">") println)

Http do(
  get("http://example.com/")
  delete("http://example.com/something")
)

Database do(
  insert("cats", list("Phil", "gray"))
  delete("cats", 12)
)
```

<sub>(Ruby has a similar feature with `Object#instance_exec`, but its object model is a bit more complicated.)</sub>

In effect, this gives you a temporary namespace, which is nice for writing domain specific languages. Is there a technique to achieve a similar effect (a temporary namespace) in Haskell?

For example, something like: (Not necessarily exactly like this, but something with similarly succinct syntax.)

```
main = do
  http $ do
    get "http://example.com/"
    delete "http://example.com/something"
  database $ do
    insert "cats" ["Phil", "gray"]
    delete "cats" 12
```

Notice that the two `delete`s are completely different functions. I'd prefer to avoid writing things like `H.delete` and `D.delete`, because that would get messy quick. I realize that this could be avoided by renaming that database version to, for example, `deleteFrom`, but I don't want to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636107/polymorphism-in-haskell

Maybe you can make your arguments hava different type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"That is crazy dynamic stuff.  You could never do that in a static language..."

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams, Rank2Types #-}
import Text.Printf
http :: (((?get :: String -> IO ()),
          (?delete :: String -> IO ())) 
         => IO a)
        -> IO a
http a = let ?get    = \s -> printf "http get %s\n" s
             ?delete = \s -> printf "http delete %s\n" s
         in a

database :: (((?insert :: String -> [String] -> IO ()),
              (?delete :: String -> Integer -> IO ())) 
               => IO a) 
            -> IO a
database a = let ?insert = \s ls -> printf "database insert %s %s\n" s (show ls)
                 ?delete = \s n  -> printf "database delete %s %d\n" s n
             in a

main = do
  http $ do
    ?get "http://example.com/"
    ?delete "http://example.com/something"
  database $ do
    ?insert "cats" ["Phil", "gray"]
    ?delete "cats" 12
```

"that is crazy.  No way it works"

```
*Main> :l Crazy.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Crazy.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> main
http get http://example.com/
http delete http://example.com/something
database insert cats ["Phil","gray"]
database delete cats 12
```

you should probably not actually do things this way.  But if that is really what you want, implicit parameters are probably the most elegant way to get it

---

applicative's RecordWildCard solution is in some sense better than this since it takes less code to set up, and involves a much smaller extension to the language.  Furthermore it is very similar to using "open" directives in languages with proper module systems, or "using namespace" commands in languages with flexible name spacing (Haskell has neither).  The implicit parameter solution captures something similar to the semantics of dynamic languages.  In particular, using it you can call a function that uses the implicit arguments, and not have to worry about manually passing the environment.

You can also simulate implicit parameters here with a ReaderT or something like it.  Although (for various reasons), that is not very compositional if you want to stay in Haskell 98.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the method of `RecordWildCards` much discussed recently in a flurry of extremely interesting posts e.g. this one on [reddit/r/haskell](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/wp229/recordwildcards_for_localised_module_imports_what/) and a ['modular-prelude' repo](https://github.com/DanBurton/modular-prelude) dissected [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/wte7w/modularprelude_with_firstclass_modules_a_la/) and finally this [tutorial post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/first-class-modules-without-defaults.html) discussed [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/wtx32/first_class_modules_without_defaults/)

On one way of using the method we'd need two helper modules (these merely imitate your intended ones):

```
module HTTP where
import System.Directory

data Http = Http {get :: String -> IO String, delete :: String -> IO ()}

http :: Http
http = Http {get = fmap reverse . readFile, delete = removeFile}
```

and

```
module DB where
import System.Directory

data DB = Db {get :: String -> IO String, insert :: String -> String -> IO ()}

db :: DB
db = Db readFile appendFile
```

then import them, using `RecordWildCards` to realize something like your plan:

```
{-#LANGUAGE RecordWildCards#-}
import           DB   -- qualified imports might be better
import           HTTP     -- but aren't needed in this case

main =  do 
  let Http{..} = http
  do test <- get "test.txt"
     delete "test2.txt"
     putStrLn $ take 10 test

  let Db{..} = db
  do test3 <- get "test3.txt"
     insert "test4.txt" "happy" 
     putStrLn $ take 10 test3 
     get "test4.txt" >>= putStrLn
```

This is a little less ugly than the `ImplicitParams` approach and more flexible than Daniel Wagner's approach, which is otherwise the most handsome.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility. The problem with Daniel Wagner's solution (and the reason I asked the question) is it gets quite a bit less handsome when you add, for example, `post`, `put`, `options`, `trace`, and `head` on the HTTP side and `update`, `drop`, `alterTable`, `createTable`, `createIndex`, `createTrigger`, `truncate`, `grant`, and `revoke` on the database side.

Comment: Just to be sure. This actually compiles with a recent enough ghc, right?

Comment: It compiles with ghc-7.4. I think the RecordWildCards extension has been around for several years.

Comment: This is just AWESOME! Never thought of using RecordWildCards in that way. With this let-binding trick, (explicit) dictionaries become more elegant than the abuse of type classes (which are implicit dictionaries).

Answer (score 15):

Just for fun, here's a translation of Philip JF's answer that doesn't use any crazy extension nonsense. In fact, it's quite boring, once you've worked out how to do it:

```
import Text.Printf

http :: ((String -> IO ()) -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO a)
     -> IO a
http a = a (printf "http get %s\n") (printf "http delete %s\n")

database :: ((String -> [String] -> IO ()) -> (String -> Integer -> IO ()) -> IO a) 
         -> IO a
database a = a (\s -> printf "database insert %s %s\n" s . show)
               (printf "database delete %s %d\n")

main = do
  http $ \get delete -> do
    get "http://example.com/"
    delete "http://example.com/something"
  database $ \insert delete -> do
    insert "cats" ["Phil", "gray"]
    delete "cats" 12
```