# Creating polymorphic functions in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, polymorphism

A short search didn't help me to find the answer, so I started to doubt in its existance. The question is simple. I want to create a polymorphic function, something like this:

```
f :: String -> String
f s = show (length s)

f :: Int -> String
f i = show i
```

A function defined differently for different data types is meant. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636107/polymorphism-in-haskell/12627564#12627564

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Haskell handle overloading polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636107/how-does-haskell-handle-overloading-polymorphism)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two flavors of polymorphism in Haskell:

- parameteric polymorphism; and
- bounded polymorphism

The first is the most general -- a function is parametrically polymorphic if it behaves uniformly for all types, in at least one of its type parameters.

For example, the function `length` is polymorphic -- it returns the length of a list, no matter what type is stored in its list.

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

The polymorphism is indicated by a lower case type variable.

Now, if you have custom behavior that you want to have for a certain *set* of types, then you have bounded polymorphism (also known as "ad hoc"). In Haskell we use type classes for this.

The class declares which function will be available across a set of types:

```
class FunnyShow a where
    funnyshow :: a -> String
```

and then you can define instances for each type you care about:

```
instance FunnyShow Int where
    funnyshow i = show (i+1)
```

and maybe:

```
instance FunnyShow [Char] where
   funnyshow s = show (show s)
```

Comment: And is the `funnyshow` just a regular function, or it has some specific things to have in mind when using it?

Comment: It is a regular function. You will have a compile error if you try to use it on a type for which you don't have an instance.

Comment: Thanks, this really seems to be the correct solution. However, it's strange that I haven't noticed usage of `instance` in several haskell programs I looked at.

Comment: @chersanya: Have you used `show`? `==`/`/=`?  `<`/`<=`/`>`/`>=`? Or `+`/`-`/`*`? Those are all (some of the) functions from type classes in the Prelude: [`Show`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Show), [`Eq`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Eq), [`Ord`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Ord), and [`Num`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t:Num), respectively. So you don't see many `instance`s because much of that has been done for you.

Comment: @chersanya: It isn't *that* surprising. An instance for some type only needs to be declared once to be used everywhere, and most of the standard types have standard instances already declared. This is more the type of code you expect to see in libraries defining new types than in normal programs. Also, common classes like `Show` and `Eq` can be specified with `deriving` where the compiler writes the instance for you, so if you've seen something like `deriving (Show, Eq)`, you've just seen a different way to declare an instance.

Comment: I don't think bounded and ad hoc polymorphism are the same. Bounded polymorphism is the result of mixing parametric polymorphism with subtyping (which BTW haskell does not have), so you can define bounds on your type parameters.

Answer (score 14):

Here is how you can achieve something similar using type families.

Well if you have same return types then you can achieve the behaviour without using type families and just using type classes alone as suggested by Don.

But it is better to use type families when you want to support more complex adhoc polymorphism, like different return types for each instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class F a where
    type Out a :: * 
    f :: a -> Out a

instance F String where  
    type Out String = String
    f = show . length

instance F Int where 
    type Out Int = String 
    f = show 

instance F Float where 
    type Out Float = Float
    f = id
```

In ghci

```
*Main> f (2::Int)
"2"

*Main> f "Hello"
"5"

*Main> f (2::Float)
2.0
```

Comment: How can `length` return a `String`? :)

Comment: @is7s Sorry, I didn't changed it completely after author modified the question..  Thanks .. corrected ..

Comment: I didn't see `type Out...` before. I think without it will work as well. Is it used to disambiguate???

Comment: @jaider see the type of f. it depends on type of Out a. You can read more about type families.